# Toyota Camry no response from turning key, no dashboard lights but headlights alright

Tags: toyota, camry

So I was driving my Toyota Camry, it's a 1995 v6 le. Everything was fine then I turned my windshield wipers off and the dash lights got extremely bright then dim and my speedometer and rpm gauge were going nuts. My car started going from bright to dim bright to dim. So I pulled over and turned it off thinking if I start it back up maybe it would be alright to get back home. When I turned the key I got no response at all from the car. No dashboard light coming on, no tick sound  or anything.  But strangely my headlights still work, my inside car lights, and the noise when the doors open and my keys are in. But like I said I have nothing from the dashboard, blinkers have no response. What would be the problem here? Please help and thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

i did some quick googling and found this: https://www.justanswer.com/toyota/7ohp9-96-toyota-camry-wont-turn-no-dash-lights-turn.html . it appears that the 100amp alternator fuse blew causing a very similar scenario to yours. thread also contains a small tutorial om how to replace said fuse if blown